# あまり気持ちのいいものではない in this context

Tags: reading-comprehension

girl X who the MC has never met before, suddenly appears and says that she is he MC's fiance

> 俺だって、興味がない訳じゃない。
>
> 会ったこともない人との絆があるって言われても正直ピンとこないし、**あまり気持ちのいいものではない。**
>
> それに、もし、Xと俺が許嫁となる運命であるのならば……こんな綺麗な女の子とケッコンかぁ……。それもいいかもしれない。

in this section the speaker is not entirely opposed to this situation in the 1st statement and quite positive in 3rd.

What i have trouble with is the "あまり気持ちのいいものではない"/"I'm really not alright with this" statement followed by "それに、もし、this would be pretty nice since she's so beautiful" .

Logically it would make much more sense if "あまり気持ちのいいものではない" was a positive statement for "それに、もし、Xと俺..." to add on to.

Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

あまり気持ちのいいものではない means something negative, "It's not very pleasing". それに indeed means "on top of that", "in addition", etc. So, as you said, logically speaking, something negative should follow.

But human emotion is not always logical. Here, he started the sentence with それに to continue something negative, but in the middle of the sentence, at the point of the first `……`, he "imagined something", and his logical thinking was interrupted.

> それに、もし、Xと俺が許嫁となる運命であるのならば……こんな綺麗な女の子とケッコンかぁ……。それもいいかもしれない。
>
> On top of that, if X and I were destined to marry......*(um, wait, on second thought....)* a marriage with a beautiful girl like this? Can it be...good?

In other words, this apparent lack of logic is how the author expressed the confusion of the protagonist.